# Appropriate representation for lazy array in Haskell

Tags: arrays, haskell, data-structures, lazy-evaluation, repa

I'm trying to make a program that has massive updates on one large array, but evaluates only few times. I want computations to be lazy as possible, but I can't find out which Array representation is good for my case.
To be specific, I want my array to:

- have fixed size
- access in constant time
- update n elements in O(n)
- **lazy evaluated**

How to approach these requirements? As a sub-question: are there libraries specifically geared for this use case?

---

EDIT:

Maybe my question wasn't specific enough, so I'll try to explain about my case more.

I'm trying to represent various size of image which can be either relatively small(about 1200x800), or much larger than that(at least 8000x8000). Also, there will be lots of layers for one image, which means that if I want to draw image on screen, there will be lots of updates on frame buffer image. I thought if I can exploit lazy-evaluated nature of haskell, I would be able to write on frame buffer only once, rather than overwriting same pixel at each updates.

I'm aware of several options for representing array in haskell, but all of those doesn't seem to fit in my case. For example:

- Data.Seq, Data.IntTrie : can't be accessed in constant time
- Data.Vector, Data.Array : update n elements takes more than O(n)
- Unboxed variants : not lazy-evaluated(I guess?)

What approach should I take in this situation?

Comment: This kind of question is off topic (though it's a good question, I have often wondered about this too). [`Seq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.8.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html) certainly aims in the right direction, perhaps you could change your question to ask whether that specific type fulfills your requirements.

Comment: @leftaroundabout sorry about that, but could you tell me why this is off topic?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I have edited the question in an attempt to tone down the recommendation aspect. (@Yang: Quoting the relevant question closure reason: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.")

Comment: @duplode Thank you for your edit, and I'm terribly sorry that I didn't notice that. I'll double-check the rules next time.

Comment: "but evaluates only few times"/"lazy evaluated" - I don't understand your requirements here.

Comment: Yes, there are a number of possibilities depending on what operations you need, whether you are using it persistently (using old versions after you have updated), if you are doing pointwise modifications only or whether your are concatenating and resizing, etc.  It's hard to make a recommendation without more of these requirements specified.

Comment: Data.Seq, Data.Vector, Data.DList, Data.IntTrie, Data.Array.ST.Lazy all come to mind to look into.  Maybe more ideas once I hear more about the use case

Comment: Given your updated use case, take a look at `UArray`, `STUArray`, and `IOUArray` from [`array`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.1.1) and maybe even `Array` from [`repa`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.2). The first three are all unboxed and pretty bare metal (you can choose mutable or not). The last is good for choosing exactly when to allocate memory (as opposed to being lazy) and for parallelizing operations.

Comment: @Alec According to the documentation, repa and unboxed arrays are strict on their elements, so I think they don't fit in my case.

Comment: @Yang Repa has a [delayed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.2/docs/Data-Array-Repa.html#t:D) representation which allows you to manipulate "delayed" arrays where actual allocation happens only when you try to materialize the array in an unboxed (and necessarily strict) form using something like [`computeUnboxedP`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.2/docs/Data-Array-Repa.html#v:computeUnboxedP). IIRC delayed arrays aren't strict.

Comment: @Alec Wow, I didn't notic that there is delayed representation! I think it fits in my case, but it seems there are not enough documentation about that. Could you explain a bit more about it?

Comment: @Yang Sure - I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One library to consider is [`repa`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.2). One of the key ideas in `repa` is that the [`Array`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.2/docs/Data-Array-Repa.html#t:Array) type is parametrized over its underlying representation. A sample of these is

- the delayed representation [`D`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.2/docs/Data-Array-Repa.html#t:D) for arrays that "aren't real" - they just compute elements on demand;
- the unboxed vector representations [`U`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.2/docs/Data-Array-Repa.html#t:U) for unboxed data
- the boxed vector representation [`V`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.2/docs/Data-Array-Repa.html#t:V) for boxed data (use only if you can't make an `Unbox` instance of your data)
- a reference to a foreign buffer [`F`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.2/docs/Data-Array-Repa-Repr-ForeignPtr.html#t:F), especially useful if you want to be writing into some foreign bitmap graphics buffer

When you compile  your code, delayed arrays will get optimized away. It goes without saying that the unboxed arrays have `O(1)` access. For your case, you will probably just be using arrays of shape [`DIM2`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.2/docs/Data-Array-Repa-Index.html#t:DIM2) (2D arrays).

For demonstration purposes, here is a program that does something similar to what you want: It takes in a list of bitmap layers and their offsets, as well as background bitmap. Then, it draws these layers on top of the bitmap background. It depends on [`repa-io`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.1) for loading the images into `repa` arrays.

```
import Data.Array.Repa.IO.BMP
import Data.Array.Repa.Shape
import Data.Array.Repa
import Data.Word

-- This is our internal representation of a bitmap
type Image s = Array s DIM2 (Word8, Word8, Word8)
data Layer s = Layer { image :: Image s, offset :: (Int, Int) }

drawLayersOnBg :: Image U -> [Layer U] -> Image D
drawLayersOnBg background layers = foldl (\bg (Layer im (x,y)) -> overlay bg (ix2 y x) im) (delay background) layers
  where
    overlay :: Image D -> DIM2 -> Image U -> Image D
    overlay bg off ov = backpermuteDft bg
                                       (\i -> let i' = i `subDim` off
                                                 in if extent ov `inShape` I'
                                                      then Just i'
                                                      else Nothing)
                                       ov

    subDim :: DIM2 -> DIM2 -> DIM2
    subDim (Z :. y :. x) (Z :. dy :. dx) = ix2 (y - dy) (x - dx)

main = do
  Right bg <- readImageFromBMP "background.bmp"
  Right l1 <- readImageFromBMP "layer1.bmp"
  Right l2 <- readImageFromBMP "layer2.bmp"
  Right l3 <- readImageFromBMP "layer3.bmp"

  out <- computeP $ drawLayersOnBg bg [ Layer l1 (200,100) , Layer l2 (100, 200), Layer l3 (-300,400) ]
  writeImageToBMP "out.bmp" out
```

With some random bitmaps from the internet I got this as an output:

[image: output]

If I wanted to, I could even have used `fromForeignPtr` to read bitmaps straight from some foreign memory buffer and `computeIntoP` instead of `computeP` to write the bitmap output straight into some foreign memory buffer (no intermediate allocations). If you need high-performance, those are especially interesting.